# Trying to Learn ASP.NET MVC, I load in the default Core Web APP MVC, but I get errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to follow this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfEjDD8mWYg&t=933s . When I create and try to run issexpress. I get 5 build errors. I'm coming from JS, but brand new to C# and VS Studio. I have a feeling this has to do with me including the Identity stuff, but I cannot figure out why it's working off the rip for the tutorial, but not for me. Any advice?

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

I tried running the same create app without the Identity login stuff, and it opened just fine, but I'd like to make an app with logins. I am just expecting to create the app, then be able to run and open the site, so I can dive into this tutorial and learning.

Comment: It may be that you don't have the official NuGet package source registered on your machine, or you do have it and it's disabled. In Visual Studio, go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings. Then click on Package Sources on the left if you're not already on that. Do you have an entry for `nuget.org` pointing to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`? Is it enabled? If not, add and enable it. Then try to build again, which should cause the packages to be able to restore.

Comment: I've been using stackoverflow for over a year now and never had to ask my own question, but thank you so much! This fixed it. I've been searching for the answer for like 2 hours now lol. 

Can you clarify or help me understand how I missed this? I didn't see it in any of the docs that I needed to set up anything to do with nuget.org.  I'm actually curious why it's not an automatic thing when starting with a template.

Comment: The template itself has nothing to do with how NuGet is configured on your machine. It says what packages it needs, but not where to get them from. Most of the time this is fine, because almost everyone has nuget.org already set up. As for why it wasn't on your machine, perhaps you installed NuGet earlier (and thus got a nuget.config file) and it didn't include nuget.org, then when you installed VS it didn't want to overwrite your nuget.config. Just a theory.

Comment: That makes sense to me, I probably should've paid more attention when installing all this new stuff. I appreciate you taking time to help me out! I'll do some more reading on nuget while I'm learning.

Comment: As for why I thought maybe you're missing the source: it says right there in your question that it's looking at Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, but nothing about looking online for those packages at nuget.org, leading me to believe that nuget.org was missing or disabled. Having a good understanding of the end-to-end process helps debug these things, though it's something you gain with time.